# Why does Joomla 2.5 SEF URL includes view as a query parameter?

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a menu item (#1066) with following Link value (as seen from admin menu-management page):
`index.php?option=com_provider&view=providerproducts`

I have a link on a page:
`index.php?option=com_provider&view=providerproducts&Itemid=1066`

When SEF URLs is turned on, URL is rewritten as:
`/products-and-services?view=providerproducts`

notice that view parameter passed explicitly.

But using URL without view, i.e. `/products-and-services` works fine.

**Question**:
Am I doing something wrong? Why does default router keeps view parameter even though it is redundant?

Note, removing view from the raw URL (i.e. `/index.php?option=com_provider&Itemid=1066`) results in SEF URL `/products-and-services`, which is good, but this won't work with SEF URL turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The com_provider component's router probably has no unset for the view parameter.   If this is a component you have written yourself, then make sure that it is being dealt with.

I assume "providerproducts" is your default view, so it assumes this is the one to show and renders the page correctly without it.

edit:

"The default router" does not unset the view.  For example, go to components/com_content/router.php and you will see that they unset the view in the core components too.

This will be because a component can change its view dynamically from within, but cannot change its Itemid or component name - which are set once when you create a menu item.

For example, if your component had two views, you may not want to set up a menu item for each view, but would want it to be created dynamically, eg /products-and-services and /products-and-services/view2  - since that "view2" segment is coming from the name of the view, then that URL structure has to be defined in the component's router.

If the view was unset in the menu router instead then the urls would be /products-and-services and /products-and-services?view=view2 (or attempt /products-and-services and /products-and-services , making a second view impossible) since it would not know how to handle a second view.

Comment: I don't provide custom router for my component, i.e. SEF URL is built by default router at /includes/router.php and it does not unset view. So my question is why. I think it would be pretty easy to tweak it to unset view if view is specified in the menu, but I suspect there are reasons they did not include that in the default router. I want to know why was it done this way.